# Как реализовать снег на кнопке

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать снег на кнопке средствами css?

Получаеться только картинкой через `:after`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересна реализация именно самого снега не картинкой, или это не имеет смысла, проще/лучше картинкой?

Comment: `CSS` предназначен для других задач, если на то пошло=) Поэтому проще, да и лучше картинкой

Comment: а вообще если заказчик хочет это облако, не стесняйтесь пихать картинки куда не попадя, ибо думать надо было ему, перед тем как такой дизайн согласовывать)))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну svg можно реализовать, но мысль от картинки недалеко будет. Чисто через css вы это облако не нарисуете.

Comment: Спасибо, буду делать картинкой, это не облако, это снег)